# Delphi XE2 DBExpress Access Violation?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I seem to be having some problems with dbExpress in Delphi XE2. When I try to set the connected property of the Sqldataconnection to true I get an access violation at 000000000.

The same thing happens when I try to change the CommandText or Active Properties of the SqlDataSet.

This is my first time using these components as I am following along with some tutorials from a book that I have so it may very well be something I am going wrong but I'm not exactly sure at this point.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which driver and database you're using?

Comment: You're sure your Sqldataconnection points to an instance, i.e. it is not nil?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I am using Mysql 5.5, the driver is mysql as well.

Do I need to move the dlls to the same directory as my exe maybe?

Comment: Also, the vendorlib is LIBMYSQL.dll

Comment: Also, if it makes any difference, when I try to compile I get the following error - [DCC Fatal Error] C15e02u.pas(7): F1026 File not found: 'Data.DBXMySQL.dcu' (unit scope "Data" indicates Win64, OSX32, Win32 only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the reason for my problems. Apparently the dbexpress drivers needed to connect to any database besides interbase are not available in Delphi XE2 starter which is what I am using.

Thanks for the help.